# "Пристройство животных" — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Увидела в Интернете слово "пристройство": ***пристройство*** бездомных собак и кошек.

Понятно, что нет такого слова. А как правильно сказать, чтобы было кратко и понятно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне вспомнился анекдот, приписываемый Чернышевскому:

> В споре о богатстве русского и французского языков мнения разошлись. Убедительнейшим аргументом в пользу превосходства первого оказались приставочные глаголы.
> — Мне кажется, что очень легко доказать богатство и превосходство русского языка перед французским.
> — Как? Что? Докажите! — закричало ему несколько голосов.
> — Да вот, господа! Про меня можно сказать, что я заплешивел. Этот глагол выражает начало, основание к дальнейшему следствию. Про Ивана Ивановича  должно сказать, что он пооплешивел. Этот глагол, как вы сами понимаете, выражает, что Иван Иванович не совсем еще плешив, но порядочно подвинулся к своей цели. Петр Петрович , конечно, не обидится и не станет спорить, если я скажу про него, что он оплешивел, так как этот глагол означает почти конченное событие. Про Сергея Ильича я имею полное право сказать, что он переплешивел, т. е. вдался в излишество по части волос, а если бы здесь был Трофим Петрович, то он, наверное, согласился бы со мною, что он уже отплешивел, т. е. исполнил все по этой части и ничего более уже сделать не может. Извольте перевести все эти глаголы на французский язык, и тогда я соглашусь, что он богаче русского.

Из приведённых в качестве примера глаголов, только "заплешивел" можно назвать литературным. Так что, если б спор проходил бы в наше время, то верх одержали бы "французы"? Я не думаю, что стоит ограничивать словотворчество литературной нормой, особенно если понятие относительно новое. Приюты для животных стали распространёнными только в XX веке.

Что касается литературного аналога, то им по идее должен стать вариант: **призрение** *бездомных собак и кошек*. Но звучит больно уж высокопарно, да и далеко не каждый поймёт, спутав с более частотным "презрением".

В целом, мне вариант "пристройство" в данном контексте кажется оптимальным.

Comment: Согласна с Вами. Если нет соответствующего слова, то его стоит изобрести. А вот только что из "Вестей": внимание на британскую монархиню(т.е. королеву). Первый раз услышала. В словарях - с пометой разговорное. Неужели настолько распространено, что уже и в официальных репортажах употребляется?

Comment: Оплешивел  -  тоже  литературное.

Answer (score 3):

Глагол пристроить (кого-то куда-то). Отглагольные существительные : пристройство, пристроение. Ср. : устроить, устройство, устроение. Нет в словарях, так будет, дело времени.
Дополнение.
Я не нашел *пристраивания* в Нацкорпусе. *Пристройство* - есть!

> Татьяна Соломатина. Девять месяцев, или «Комедия женских положений» (2010)
> Ты у нас сообразительная **в плане пристройства ребёнка**.
>
> Обзор сайта Трибуна защиты животных (2004)
> Не выживает никто: как погибают котята, **отданные для пристройства** добрым благодетельницам ― продавцам животных с Птичьего рынка
>
> М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. В среде умеренности и аккуратности (1874-1877)
> А коль скоро человек «пристроен к делу», коль скоро он надел на себя вещественный знак **этого пристройства** (чиновничий вицмундир или приказчичью чуйку ― это все равно), так тотчас же он сделался человеком «нужным», а следовательно, и известным.

Answer (score 2):

Слово уже есть - *пристраивание*. Образовано от *пристроить* в его разговорном значении: поместить, определить, устроить кого-, что-л. где-л., куда-л.

Comment: Глагол пристраивать - несовершенного вида. Подходит ли в данном случае отглагольное существительное *пристраивание*? Длительный незавершенный процесс с малопонятным результатом, а несчастному животному требуется решительное действие? Нет, пристраивание **не пойдет**, и не уговаривайте!

Comment: Несчастному животному лучше знакомое "пристраивание", чем подозрительное "пристройство": а вдруг там юные патологоанатомы будут изучать собачье устройство?

Comment: Вы сами животных пристраивете? У моего подъезда живут несколько кошек, а с торца, где служебный вход в хлебный магазин, пристроились четыре собаки. Сутками лежат и ждут кормежки. Спят, жмурятся, не скандалят, не гавкают. Просто ждут. Пристраивание состоялось. Но пристройство - это другое.

Comment: Пристраивание  это  процесс,  которым  занимаются.  Можно  пристраивать  людей,  можно  животных.  Слово  уже  есть,  литературное,  смотрится  гораздо  лучше,  чем  пристройство.

Comment: Добавил в своем ответе аргумент о литературности.

Answer (score 1):

ПРИСТРОЙСТВО животных - это уже устоявшийся термин, который используется на всех форумах, во всех объявлениях. 
Оно составлено аналогично слову "устройство" (например, устройство ребенка в детский сад)  которое почему-то не называется "устраиванием".

Слово "устраивание" хотя и существует, но применяется не часто и не в этом значении, слово "пристраивание"  встречается крайне редко (только если в качестве "пристраивания" террасы к дачному домику).

ВЫВОДЫ

1) Очевидно, что существительное "пристраивание", соответствующее глаголу "пристраивать", используется  не для всех значений этого глагола.

2) Слово неудобно для произношения и не обладает ясно выраженной семантикой, как здесь уже отмечалось.

3) Также непонятно, в чем заключается его литературность, если оно практически не встречается в речи.

Comment: Литературность я  определил  на  слух и спорить  по  этому  поводу  не  буду.  Глагол  пристраивать (кого - то  куда - то ) очень  схож  с  глаголом  устраивать ( кого - то  куда - то )  с  некоторыми  нюансами  по  смыслу.  Я  не  соглашусь  с  вашими  пунктами  2  и  3.  Мне  кажется,  что от "пристроить"  лучше  пристраивание, а  от  "устроить" - устройство.  Пристройство  в  этом  значении  я  воспринимаю  как  неологизм,  созданный  по  схожему  по  смыслу  и  однокоренному  к  тому  же  слову  устройство.  Но  занимаются люди  именно пристраиванием  котят  в  хорошие  руки.

Comment: Кстати,  слово  пристройство  мне  программа  проверки  ошибок  подчёркивает  как  незнакомое,  а  слово  пристраивание  -  нет.  Это  к  пункту  3  вашего  ответа.

Comment: Форумы  и  объявления  не  могут  быть  образцом  грамотности,  сами  ведь  знаете.

Comment: Как появляются новые слова? Прежде всего, появляется потребность в таком слове для обозначения нового  понятия. Есть приюты, много бездомных животных, надо их туда устроить. В то же время устраивают куда-то обычно людей, но есть глагол "пристроить" разг.стиля, который подойдет для животных. Теперь надо подыскать подходящее существительное, и соискателей два: пристраивание и пристройство. Слово "пристраивание" уже готовенькое (его программа узнает и не подчеркивает), но редко употребляемое и обозначающее только действие в основном значении: что-то к чему-то пристроили.

Comment: Другой вариант - создание нового слова. Продуктивная модель, да и сам образец, для этого имеется - это слово "устройство".  Суффикс СТВ может обозначать не только действие, но и деятельность (сравнить: ловить рыбу - ловля рыбы и рыболовство). И выбор уже сделан: используется именно слово "пристройство". Наберите два эти слова в поисковике, и увидите разницу. Пристраиванием домашних животных, согласно поисковику,  занимается только Запорожский женский форум, все  остальные структуры называют это пристройством.

Comment: Слово "пристройство" ассоциируется не с "пристраивать", а с "устрой-ство" или "пристрой-ка". Если уж образовывать слово, то правильнее будет "пристроительство". Ничего хорошего в "пристройстве" не вижу, очень нелогичный, неестественный неологизм. Строить - строительство, пристроить - пристроительство. Тогда давайте и строительство на стройство заменим.

Comment: Строить - строительство (не "стройство"), расстроить - расстройство (не расстроительство), устроить - устройство (не устроительство), пристроить - пристройство (не пристроительство). Как очевидно, суффикс ТЕЛЬ, основным значением которого является лицо/предмет (жить - житель, глушить - глушитель), в слове "строительство" используется в качестве промежуточного  элемента, но с появлением приставки необходимость в нем исчезает. Логика такого словообразования оказалась доступной всем пользователям, которые выбрали "пристройство". Впрочем, если Вы скажете "пристраивание", то, думаю, вас поймут.

Comment: Тогда проще расширить значение слова "пристройка".

Comment: Андрей Белый. Почему я стал символистом (1928)  
Становилось ясно, что я, дразнимый детьми, считаемый дурачком чужими взрослыми и сжатый узами нашей квартиры с ощущением полной своей бездарности в ней ― долго не проживу эдаким способом; случится нечто непоправимое, разорвется личина-личность, выступит из Бореньки «это» , и все в ужасе ахнут, потому что «это» покажется им либо преступностью, либо безумием; чтобы отсрочить миг, я **стал пристраиваться** к «цивилизации» ; **в этом пристройстве** сложилась и первая моя стилизация, сошедшая преудачно: я стал первым учеником...

Comment: Суффикс К  чаще используется для образования ПРЕДМЕТНЫХ существительных : тереть - терка, выдумать - выдумка. Действие суффикс К обозначает намного реже, да ещё иногда со вторым предметным значением: вышивать - вышивка, заготовить - заготовка. В результате пристройка животных может быть понята как пристройка для животных.

Answer (score 0):

Затрудняюсь определить, какие из предложенных образований окказиональны, а какие ошибочны, поэтому вместо комментариев предложу вопрос: господа, что нам мешает говорить о *поиске хозяев/попечителей/рачителей/дома/крова/четырех стен*?.. Ну будет на одно слово больше. Я полагаю, на краткости и доступности для понимания существенным образом это не отразится. Впрочем, важен контекст. Замена и в самом деле требующего замены *пристройства* *призрением* возможна, пожалуй, только в том случае, если цель употребления последнего — поведать о феномене призрения животных людьми — в современности, в истории... В ином контексте слово *призрение* дает крайне смутное представление о целях сообщения (как, впрочем, и в любом контексте неудачное *пристройство*), поэтому объявление лучше озаглавить оборотом со словом *поиск*.

> Во-первых тем, что при размещении объявления 2 слова дороже одного

По-моему, сферу употребления платными объявлениями никто не ограничивал... Ну, хорошо, положим, мы стеснены в материальных средствах. Каждый, кто находится в затруднительном финансовом положении, при необходимости дать объявление известного содержания, не имеет  времени на поиск корректной формулировки и объявляет по собственному разумению: «*Котенок/щенок/*[они же во множественном числе] *в дар*», никоим образом не нарушая при этом норм языка.

> все эти выражения менее точные, чем "пристройство", так не показывают, что животное отдаётся бесплатно, а не за деньги.

Слово не зафиксировано словарем русского языка, следовательно может быть истолковано как Вашей милости угодно.

> Можно вспомнить ещё старое клише "отдам в добрые руки", но для организации такая фраза, по-моему, звучит уже неуклюже.

Для организации такая фраза обойдется в круглую сумму, поэтому вспоминать о ней нет смысла.

Comment: >господа, что нам мешает говорить о поиске хозяев/попечителей/рачителей/дома/крова/четырех стен?

Во-первых тем, что при размещении объявления 2 слова дороже одного, а Во-вторых, что самое главное, все эти выражения менее точные, чем "пристройство", так не показывают, что животное отдаётся бесплатно, а не за деньги. Можно вспомнить ещё старое клише "отдам в добрые руки", но для организации такая фраза, по-моему, звучит  уже неуклюже.

Comment: >Слово не зафиксировано словарем русского языка, следовательно может быть истолковано как Вашей милости угодно

Вообще-то нет. Исходя из морфемного анализа любой знающий русский язык укажет, что "пристройство" - это существительное от глагола "пристроить", а у "пристроить" по отношению к животным зафиксировано лишь одно значение. В словарях слова указываются всегда с запозданием, но если слово исходя из морфем понятно, то оно может быть литературным даже без фиксации в словарях (*зайчишка, пингвинообразный, обезьяненок*). На форуме как-то задавали вопрос даже о слове *нижеперечисленное*.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос № 277351**:
Грамота, с ужасом увидел слово *пристройство* (животных).
Есть ли такое слово?

[**Ответ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE) справочной службы русского языка:
Словари фиксируют только 2 отглагольных существительных к *пристроить* – это *пристраивание* (ко всем значениям глагола) и *пристройка* (только к *пристроить* в знач. "построить в дополнение к чему-либо"). Слово *пристройство* официально «прописку» в русском литературном языке не имеет (хотя и правда употребляется).

В **1863** году о слове "пристройство" ([**Н. С. Лесков. Синодальный философ**](http://az.lib.ru/l/leskow_n_s/text_1863_sinodalniy_filosof.shtml)) говорится:

«Патриотов занимало "не воспитание в русском духе, а *пристройство* (*курсив* — авт.) детей к местам, где бы они, не обременяясь сведениями и трудами, имели от самого сего настроения выгоду положения".
Слова "искательность" и "пристройство", которые и мы слыхали в нашем детстве и позабыли, снова воскресают и действуют».

Слово используется сплошь и рядом, поэтому, мне кажется, наступило время для его официальной "прописки", для его "воскресения и действия".

[**Выставка-пристройство «Всем по собаке» пройдет в Москве при звездной поддержке**](https://lenta.ru/news/2017/07/13/vsem_po_sobake/)