# Великий и богатый русский язык

Tags: общие-вопросы

Все русскоговорящие знают, что наш язык велик и богат. А кто знает, почему именно? Хотя он замечательный, но не единственный в мире.

С полгода тому назад случайно открыла видео, где кто-то пытался доказать превосходство русского языка над английским по количеству синонимов. Он привёл штук десять синонимов к слову "видеть" в сравнении с английскими двумя — "see" и "look". Я с ним абсолютно не согласна, так как: (1) человек явно плохо знает английский язык, потому что в нём синонимов не меньше, и к тому же *see* и *look* не совсем синонимы (*видеть* и *смотреть* точно также, как *слушать* и *слышать*); (2) половина из его русских синонимов — давно устаревшие слова, которые сейчас никто не использует. Даже без конкретного примера, синонимами меня трудно убедить, — во всех языках есть синонимы, где-то погуще, где-то пожиже, но везде есть. Также везде можно найти слово, которое трудно переводится на другие языки.

Недавно также увидела вот эту версию: http://www.kprf.org/showthread-t_20617.html (вкратце: только в русском можно написать рассказ, где все слова начинаются с одной буквы). Да, в романских языках это невозможно — но лишь только потому, что то, что русский делает падежами, они делают предлогами. В русском языке используется гораздо меньше предлогов, чем в европейских языках, но я не считаю, что это делает его богаче. С одной стороны, он за счёт этого более ёмкий. Но с другой стороны, все знакомые с английским, сталкивались с артиклями *the/a*. В английском есть семантическая разница между "the apple" и "an apple", а в русском — просто яблоко. Так что и это объяснение не подходит.

Где-то на форуме я видела заметку о русских приставках (был приведён коротенький рассказ о том, как можно *заплешивить*, *пооплешивить*, и т.д.), но теперь не могу её найти [правка: это ответ Марка Иза на этот вопрос: [Как сказать правильно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE) ]. Вот это, мне кажется, уже ближе к делу. Благодаря приставкам (и суффиксам), можно создавать новые слова, которые будут всем понятны. Есть не только семьи, но практически грибницы однокоренных слов, которые могут продолжать расти. В английском этого очень не хватает — поскольку язык образовался как смесь латинского (частично через французский), саксонского, с примесью греческого, норвежского, более современного французского, и других: не так много пространства, чтобы раскрыться. Вместо приставки или суффикса приходится обходится либо синонимами, либо удлинением предложения словами "совсем", "почти", и т.п.

Но если приставки кардинально изменяют значение слова, или же создают совсем новое слово, то суффиксы, в частности — уменьшительно-ласкательные, оставляют основное значение в покое, при этом слегка меняя оттенок слова. Когда я перевожу текст с русского языка на английский, я всегда спотыкаюсь об суффиксы (другие языки недостаточно знаю, чтобы комментировать, но полагаю, что история похожая). "Город" перевести легко. А попробуйте "городок" — *маленький город*? Получается совсем другое чувство, это уже не так. А "городишко"? Как передать то чувство собственного превосходства над этим небольшим населённым пунктом, выражаемое либо в умилении, либо в презрении — либо в обоих?! Ведь это никакими синонимами и предлогами не передашь! "Глаза" переводится очень просто. А "глазки", "глазоньки"? Или же в другую сторону — "глазища"?

По-моему верно, что русский язык великий и богатый. Но меня раздражает то, что люди это говорят, не задумываясь о том, почему именно он лучше остальных, или же сочиняют мнимые объяснения его превосходства. Вот это уже получается самообман.

Я считаю, что русский язык богат в основном из-за наших неповторимых суффиксов. А вы что думаете? По-вашему, на самом ли деле русский язык велик и богат, и почему?

Mне интересно узнать разные мнения.

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо, интересный вопрос. Наверное, трудно на него ответить сразу и по существу, без общих слов. Лучше всего  общими усилиями перечислить по пунктам достоинства нашего языка.

№1. Русское предложение имеет  имеет особую структуру

Грамматическая связь между словами (согласование, управление, примыкание)  обеспечивает их  свободный порядок в предложении. Из отдельных слов складываются  интонационные отрезки-фразы, и каждое предложение состоит из двух или нескольких таких фраз. Получается, что при одной и той же грамматике ПЕРЕСТАНОВКА СЛОВ обеспечивает разные оттенки смысла, нужное логическое ударение, то есть мы  имеем своеобразную многомерность русского синтаксиса.

№2. Различные стили - достоинство русского языка

Русская речь состоит из разных стилей, фактически это как бы несколько языков, различающихся по лексике, грамматике, области употребления. Для каждой ситуации подбирается подходящий стиль, но и смешение стилей имеет  коммуникативную и художественную значимость. Стилевые переходы даже в разговорной речи очень выразительны.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 20.07.14

№3 Развитая система аффиксации

В русском языке значение слова СЧИТЫВАЕТСЯ с каждой морфемы и суммируется, иногда необязательно обращаться к словарям. ПРИСТАВОК немного, но практически все они многозначные и, кроме того, выполняют важную грамматическую функцию,  изменяя вид глагола.  И  особо надо отметить информационно насыщенную систему СУФФИКСАЦИИ.  К примеру, в словаре Ефремовой только для существительного  приводится 690 значений суффиксов. Кроме словообразовательных суффиксов, существуют суффиксы субъективной оценки (уменьшительно-ласкательные, увеличительные, пренебрежительные), также важна грамматическая роль суффиксов при определении вида и характера действия (бросать – бросить, навешать – навесить).

№4 Оптимальное количество времен (дискуссионная статья)

В изъявительном наклонении  с учетом вида существует 5 временных форм:  читает (настоящее),  читал (длительное прошедшее), будет читать (будущее), прочитал (совершенное прошедшее), прочитает  (совершенное будущее). Последовательность действий также уточняется с помощью союзов и временных наречий.

Кроме того, существуют ИТЕРАТИВЫ (лат. iterativus - часто повторяемый, глаголы, обозначающие действие, совершаемое в разных направлениях, не в одно время: идти - ходить, лететь - летать). Также интересно отметить наличие КАУЗАТИВОВ (от лат. causa—причина, глаголы, вызывающие действие: поить - пить, звонить - звенеть).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 22.07.14

№5. Наличие односоставных предложений  свидетельствуют о  разнообразии и гибкости грамматики

Наличие односоставных предложений различного вида позволяет  внести  добавочные  смысловые оттенки  или упростить грамматику, избежав однообразных повторов субъекта действия (иду по лесу – идешь по лесу). Особый интерес представляют безличные и назывные предложения. Безличные предложения используются при обозначении стихийности или независимости происходящих действий, а назывные предложения просто фиксируют  (фотографируют) существование предмета  или явление в текущий момент.

Comment: Очень согласна про пункт №1. У нас на самом деле гораздо больше гибкости в синтаксисе чем во многих других языках. Я и не задумывалась об этом раньше. Спасибо!

Comment: Хороший ответ, развернутый и по существу.

Answer (score 3):

Вы видимо вспомнили [этот мой ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Если рассматривать наш язык как можно более объективно, то он прекрасно описывает отношение к предмету, но не очень хорошо - действие. Всего три времени глагола, и чрезмерно "быкающее" сослагательное наклонение, зачастую делают повествование не очень удобным. Но как только дело доходит до описания нашего отношения к предмету, то тут русский язык расцветает. Тончайшие оттенки смысла передаются с помощью суффиксов, приставок и инверсии, если б мы вслед за американцами начали учитывать в своих словарях все устаревшие слова и окказионализмы, то у нас уже было бы не то что миллион - миллиард слов. Именно этим свойством русского языка объясняется наша страсть к заимствованиям. Мы настолько хотим подчеркнуть все оттенки значения, что постоянно заимствуем из других языков слова, придавая им в итоге порой совершенно иные смыслы. Показательным примером будет латинское "интеллигенция", значение которого мы настолько переиначили под себя, что тот же английски впоследствии воспринял это слово из русского, именно в нашем понимании.

Помимо крайне удобного словообразования, отличительной чертой русского является то, что теория "трёх штилей" для русского в общем-то ещё не устарела, хоть и видоизменилась. Есть русский-матерный, русский-разговорный, литературный, канцелярит, академический, и всё это разный язык. В детстве я не общался матом, и когда судьба закинула меня в среду, где мат был нормой общения, пришлось потратить около трёх месяцев просто чтобы быстро, без внутреннего перевода, воспринимать речь.

Также удобством русского является безличная форма. На русском можно провести длительную переписку в интернете, но так и не узнать кто по другую сторону экрана, мужчина или женщина. Безличность позволяет нам без каких-либо особых проблем переносить нынешнее отсутствие обращения типа "леди и джентльмены".

Comment: По-моему, количество форм времени в языке должно быть оптимальным. Язык со временем развивается, совершенствуется. Когда-то и у нас были многочисленные прошедшие времена: аорист, имперфект, перфект, плюсквамперфект, а сейчас с учетом вида мы фактически в изъявительном наклонении имеем 5 времен - думаю, что этого вполне достаточно. 12 английских времен  тоже не идеал.

Comment: @Марк Из: Да, я думала про Ваш ответ. Спасибо за ссылку. Я её вставлю в вопрос.

Comment: @София: Английский я учила на слух, поэтому толком не знаю ни однго правила, хотя свободно на нём разговариваю, а французский пыталась учить по учебнику. Конечно, все эти времена и склонения очень затрудняют дело, но они нужны. И французский, и английский достаточно гибкие языки в этом плане.

Comment: В иврите наоборот - язык очень математический, но, хотя его было гораздо легче учить, хромой и неуклюжий в этом плане. "Делал" - очень легко, а "сделал", "делал бы", "хотел бы делать", и т.д. уже малость затруднительно. В нём не хватает форм времени.
Но в русском и в самом деле оптимальное количество. Он достаточно гибкий, но не такой... заковыристый, что-ли.

Comment: @AlenkiyTsvet..., @София, я бы всё же сказал, что оптимальным является количество времён в немецком. Плюсквамперфекта всё-таки не хватает.

*К Пугачёву подходили люди, и он принимал их в шайку*. Как тут ни изощряйся в переделке фразы, но без значительного утяжеления конструкции, определить осуществлялся приём по факту подхода, или после некого опроса, осмотра - невозможно. *Человек гулял по улице* - он сейчас гуляет, или вообще был в этом замечен? Да, чаще всего это можно выяснить из контекста, но выяснение из контекста свидетельствует как раз о недостатке средств речи.

Comment: @Марк Из: тоже согласна... я немецкого совсем не знаю, поэтому трудно судить, но мне кажется я понимаю, о чём речь.

Comment: А мне не очень понятно по поводу Пугачева. Картина развертывания действия вполне ясна: заявлений они не писали, анкету не составляли, просто называли себя и изъявляли желание "вступить в шайку". Процесс растянут во времени - подходили всё новые люди, но для каждого участника заканчивался вступлением.  А зависимость от контекста - это вполне нормально, здесь и чувствуется гибкость речи, возможность корректировки значения фразы. Она как базовый вариант, которому говорящий может придать дополнительные опции. И еще интересно: в английском языке насколько часто используются все имеющиеся времена?

Comment: Я сталкивалась с переводами с японского. Так, хочу сказать, порой встаешь перед неразрешимой задачей. У них гораздо больше слов для обозначения оттенков смысла. Например, что-то около десяти вариантов местоимения "я" в зависимости от пола, возраста, ситуации, собеседника, характера и т.д. И это только первое, что пришло на ум.

Comment: @Марк Из "Страсть к заимствованиям" у русских не от стремления к выражению множества оттенков. Во-первых, для этой цели можно легко обойтись собственными источниками, как это делают почти все восточные языки. Во-вторых, заимствования у русских тесно связаны с языком культурного влияния на определенный промежуток времени: греческий, голландский, немецкий, французский и теперь - англо-американский. Эта страсть не лингвистическая, а психологическая. Подхалимство это, лизоблюдство и пресмыкание перед доминирующей культурой.

Comment: В русском языке три **грамматических** времени, но время смысловое задается еще и видом, например: "я ходил" (past simple — простое прошедшее время) и "я сходил" (present perfect — простое совершенное время).

Answer (score 2):

Ни  один  человек  не  жалуется  на  свой  родной  язык  и  вполне  может  выразить  на  нём  всё,  что  захочет.  В  принципе,  на  каком - то  языке  больше  написано,  на  каком - то  меньше.  Единственный  повод  помериться   богатством  и  могуществом.   По  крайней  мере  подсчитать  можно.

Answer (score 0):

Длинная, достаточно, трасса.

Достаточно тёмное время года.

Достаточно молодые мужчины.

Скорее
   недостойны быть подозреваемыми.

Кран
   рухнул на проезжую часть, приятно,
   что никто не пострадал.

Достаточно
   стрессовая работа - оператор банка.

Довольно поздно вызвали пожарных.

Двигатель достаточно прожорливый.

Ребёночек достаточно рано умер.

Здесь присутствует
   пиктограмма и кнопка вызова
   проводника.

Достаточно вялый в
   воздухе самолёт.

Его настоящее имя -
   Вова, на самом деле.

Пижма от
   Екатеринбурга находится достаточно
   близко.

Воздух прогрелся до трёх и
   одного десятых градуса.

*(Из новостных передач радио и телевидения)*

Мог бы эпиграфом быть, уж больно к месту, пассаж из ответа Bernard: "Ни один человек не жалуется на свой родной язык и вполне может выразить на нём всё, что захочет". Верно. Страдает и жалеет себя до невозможности, человек читающий выражения на в той же мере  родном ему языке.